# Is not attached vs was not attached

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

I have asked someone to send me a file, but the person didn't attach the file in the reply.

Which is correct way to respond back?

1. The file is not attached
2. The file was not attached

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your examples are correct but have different focus as to the reason

> The file is not attached.

means the file *is not present* on the email the person sent.

> The file was not attached.

means the person did not attach the file *when* they sent the email.

In either case, you did not receive the attachment.

Comment: Hi Peter,

What about when you're giving information to someone? 
**It is on page 4 vs It was on page 4**

I'm reading an instruction with a friend. We are looking for 2 things in the guide book. I found the first one and I continued to read looking for the second one. As I'm looking for the second one, my friend asks me if I found any. Should I say it is on page 4 or i was on page 4?

Comment: You can use either, but there is a subtle difference. "The information **is** on page 4" can be used without additional context stating where the information can be found. "The information **was** on page 4" usually implies "*When I was looking for the information and found it*, it **was** on page 4" since otherwise it would mean the information can no longer be found on "page 4" and is now missing.